# How to use raphael and raphael free transform plugin with a image?

Tags: jquery, raphael

I've been searching for a long time is there any tutorial shows raphael free transform a image?
below code is what i tried but not work.

```
<div id="canvas">
<img src="img/product/tmp/202/1.jpeg">
<img src="img/product/tmp/202/2.jpeg">
</div>

var paper = Raphael($("#canvas"));
var img = $('#canvas').children('img').eq(0);
var ft = paper.freeTransform(img);
ft.showHandles();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DZc8f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Raphael.fn.freeTransform = function(subject, options, callback) {
   ----
-------
```

}

[Here is the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqn93/4/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I try to freeTransform is a img and change the `master, drone` = select img , can't work

Comment: If you need it for an image may be this will help you out.Because i did'nt work on image.https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/raphaeljs/-PRlwswF4_Q[1-25-false]

Comment: Cheers.happy to help.dont forget to upvote while accepting :)